# Extracting Table and Column names from SQL CREATE script using C#

Tags: c#, sql, regex

Problem:

Extracting Table and Column names from a line of SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE [ dbo ] . [ worktype_template ] ( [ worktype_key ] [ int ] NULL , [ template_key ] [ int ] NULL ) ON [ PRIMARY ]
```

I've tried with numerous Regex's and failed miserably. Any suggestions, particually in C#, would be helpful.

Comment: SQL is usually better dealt with by *parsing* and regex's aren't usually up to the job of parsing (they may be used as *part* of e.g. a lexer, as part of the parsing process)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE [ dbo ] . [ worktype_template ] ( [ worktype_key ] [ int ] NULL , [ template_key ] [ int ] NULL ) ON [ PRIMARY ]";
query = query.Replace(" . ", ".");
query = query.Replace("[ ", "[");
query = query.Replace(" ]", "]");
// Selects what is between parenthesizes 
String fieldsString = new String(query.SkipWhile(c => c != '(').TakeWhile(c => c != ')').ToArray());
// Selects the fields
String[] fields = fieldsString.Split(',').Select(line => new Regex("\\[\\w+\\]").Match(line).Value).ToArray();
// Selects table name
String tableName = new Regex("\\[\\w+\\](\\.\\[\\w+\\])*").Match(query).Value;
```

I hope it helps.